# Word Macro to colorize text in VBA format

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document that includes blocks of VBA code. Has anyone seen a macro that will format it by coloring keywords blue, comments green, and so on, so that it looks the way it appears in the VBA editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to highlight the keyword. The code works by searching for the selected range and change the word color.

You can add after the `End If` the first part of the code and change the text.
Good luck!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Set myRange = Range("A1:AG100")  'The Range that contains the substring you want to change color
    substr = "t"   'The text you want to change color
    txtColor = 3   'The ColorIndex which represents the color you want to change


    For Each myString In myRange
        lenstr = Len(myString)
        lensubstr = Len(substr)
        For i = 1 To lenstr
            tempString = Mid(myString, i, lensubstr)
            If tempString = substr Then
                myString.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lensubstr).Font.ColorIndex = txtColor
            End If
        Next i
    Next myString

     Set myRange = Range("A1:AG100")  'The Range that contains the substring you want to change color
    substr = "u"   'The text you want to change color
    txtColor = 4   'The ColorIndex which represents the color you want to change
      For Each myString In myRange
        lenstr = Len(myString)
        lensubstr = Len(substr)
        For i = 1 To lenstr
            tempString = Mid(myString, i, lensubstr)
            If tempString = substr Then
                myString.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lensubstr).Font.ColorIndex = txtColor
            End If
        Next i
    Next myString
End Sub
```